# Fit linear model on all data after doing it just on training data in order to make predictions about future data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, model, linear-regression

In linear regression (but in general on any other model) is there a need to use `.fit()` on all input data after using it only on training data? I'll try to explain it better with an example. I will artificially create a trivial set of input and output data:

```
import numpy as np
from random import uniform
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

X = np.arange(0, 500, 5).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.zeros(100)
for i in range(len(X)):
    y[i] = 3 * X[i] + uniform(-10, 10)

X_train = X[:80]
y_train = y[:80]

X_test = X[80:]
y_test = y[80:]

reg = LinearRegression()
```

It could be seen as a time series (`X` contains the time periods).
Now, I train the model using the training sets:

```
reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

and I make predictions using the testing set:

```
y_pred = reg.predict(X_test)
```

Using `r2_score(y_test, y_pred)` I get about 0.99, so my model is able to fit the data correctly.

Now my question: I want to make a prediction about the future, i.e. about a series of data not contained in `X`, let's say:

```
X_future = np.arange(500, 525, 5).reshape(-1, 1)
```

Should I proceed this way:

```
y_future = reg.predict(X_future)
```

or in this:

```
reg.fit(X, y)
y_future = reg.predict(X_future)
```

In other words, do I have to fit again the model found earlier on the entire `(X, y)` before making a prediction of the future? Are there any chances that both approaches are correct?

Thanks to anyone who will answer me.

Comment: an already trained model is used on test data, thereby checking unknown data (out of sample). If you train the model again on new data, how do you check if the model has retrained (the training data will have a good prediction and the test data will have a bad result)?

Comment: @inquirer Yes, the first option is more reasonable (also because it would be a bit counterintuitive to re-train the model). I was wondering if there was a way to update the model with test data.